# Не запускается отладка и конструктор UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Переустановил винду 10, после чего сразу на чистую поставил Visual 2015 Pro. Запускаю совершенно новый проект и вижу, что не запускается конструктор:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
[8712] Конструктор внезапно прервал выполнение!
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IIsolationDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String assemblyCodeBase, String typeName)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Ну ладно, запускаю на компиляцию и тут происходит то, что на картинках. Отладчик присоединен, но не настроен на обработку данного исключения. Приложение совершенно новое, код вставляла сама вижла при создании, ошибок не может быть в принципе.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Что за ерунда происходит?

P.S. C jit что-то не то:

[image: 3]

Режим разработчика включен:
[image: 4]

Журнал:
После запуска конструктора:
[image: 5]

После запуска отладки
[image: 6]

Инфа о системе и Visual:
[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Один раз выскочила вот такое исключение:

```
System.Exception
Предоставленный пакет уже установлен, и переустановка пакета заблокирована. Подробности см. в журнале событий AppXDeployment-Server.

Windows не удается зарегистрировать пакет 8af00aa2-f9bf-4e46-943d-db762c5748e5, так как используется режим разработки, а пакет уже установлен. Увеличьте версию пакета, который нужно зарегистрировать, или удалите перед регистрацией старый пакет для всех пользователей в системе.
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Раньше, в настройках, стояло по умолчанию установка приложения на D. На диске появились две папки WindowsApp и еще какая-то, название к сожалению не помню, которые я благополучно удалил, предварительно вернув установку на C диск. Проблема не решилась.

Папка называется WpSystem, которая, почему-то, не хочет удаляться. Точнее она удалятся, но появляется снова.

Comment: В журнале что пишет?

Comment: Где его найти???

Comment: Включен режим разработчика?

Comment: да, студия запросила самостоятельно, и я его сразу включил.

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, журнал ищется в Пуск -> Администрирование -> Просмотр событий

Comment: Выложил скрины журнала.

Comment: У меня был похожий баг после смены в настройках диска для универсальных приложений с С на D. Исправили его в последней инсайдерской сборке

Comment: Вернул на С - не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разных источниках такая проблема решалась по разному, перепробовал кучу методов, но ничего не помогло. Решил проблему кардинально - полностью переустановил Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка возникает если изменить диск по умолчанию для универсальных приложений. Ошибка исправлена в Windows 10 сборке 14295

[UWP projects couldn't be run after changing storage folder in Settings](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2558411/uwp-projects-couldnt-be-run-after-changing-storage-folder-in-settings)